# How to build assets separately from the rest of the app with Parcel

Tags: parceljs

I have a project that I am building with parcel. Since it is mostly static, I only have some files that should be updated once a day, I put the project on aws s3 bucket. I am thinking of updating the files that should be updated once a day, with a lambda function. But, in my project that is structured like this:

```
src/
   assets/
   components/
   main.js
   ...
```

In the folder assets, I have two other folders data and icons. Data folder holds json files that should be updated once a day.

```
assets/data/
      /icons/
```

When I run parcel to build a project, I see that all files inside icons folder are built as individual files.

[image]

How can I make files inside the data folder to build separately so that I know which files I need to target in order to update them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy) **parcel-plugin-static-files-copy**
that does exactly what I need. Only had to add this to my package.json:

```
"staticFiles": {
  "staticPath": "src/assets/data"
}
```