# How to serve a json file with parcel without bundling it?

Tags: json, assets, parceljs

I'm making a project with parcel and typescript. It works great, but for one library I'm using, I would need to host a bunch of .json-files at a fixed directory:

The files look as following:

```
index.html
index.ts
tiles/
 | file.json
 | file0.json
 | subdirectory with *.json
```

In `package.json`, I include them as `parcel *.html tiles/*` (for `start`) and `parcel build index.html tiles/*`, but this results in the json files to be build into some .js file. I however need them to be served as is.

Any hints on how to tell parcel *not* to bundle them?

Comment: Possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61839773/how-to-build-assets-separately-from-the-rest-of-the-app-with-parcel

Answer (score 9):

You can override the transformer plugin used for JSON files in the `.parcelrc` file. It defaults to using `@parcel/transformer-json`, but you can use `@parcel/transformer-raw` to treat JSON files as assets.

### .parcelrc

```
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "*.json": ["@parcel/transformer-raw"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a npm-package doing exactly this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy

`npm install -D parcel-plugin-static-files-copy` to install (for development only)

Then, in `package.json`, add:

````
"staticFiles": {
    "staticPath": [
      {
        "staticPath": "tiles", -- copy all files from this directory at the root from your project...
        "staticOutDir": "tiles/" -- ... to this directory in dist/, so it becomes dist/tiles/<files>
      }
    ]
  }

``` 

Note that you have to define a `staticPath` in the list `staticPath`, this is a bit confusing at first.
````

Comment: Yes, this method works, I have done the same thing in a recent project.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Parcel 2, you can do something like this:

```js
import jsonUrl from 'url:./data.json'

// Fetch the file asynchronously from the URL
fetch(jsonUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => ...)
  ... etc. ...
```